# How can I allow a user to input a list using parentheses and convert this to Mathematica notation dynamically?

Tags: dynamic

I have the following dynamic module.  It works.  The problem is that whenever I try to make the variable *list* or the variable *s* dynamic the code doesn't work.

My goal is to allow students to enter a list of points using familiar mathematical notation.  That is, user inputs "(4, 5), (9, 0)" and this gets converted to

{{4, 5}, {9,0}}

Suggestions would be greatly appreciated.  I can not for the life of me figure this out.

```
DynamicModule[{list = "((5, 6), (9, 0))", s},
   Panel[
    Column[
      {
       Labeled[InputField[Dynamic[list], String, FieldSize -> {50, 5}],StringForm["Data Points"], Left],
       s = ToExpression[StringReplace[list, {"(" -> "{", ")" -> "}"}] ],
       ListPlot[s]
      }
     ]
   ]
 ]
```

Comment: You don't need `ToString[]` and `ToExpression` (inside `ListPlot`). This works : `DynamicModule[{list = "((5, 6), (9, 0))", s}, 
 Panel[Column[{Labeled[
     InputField[Dynamic[list], String, FieldSize -> {50, 5}], 
     StringForm["Data Points"], Left], 
    s = ToExpression[StringReplace[list, {"(" -> "{", ")" -> "}"}]], 
    StringQ[s], s, ListPlot[s, PlotStyle -> PointSize[0.05]]}]]]`/

Comment: You are correct.  I had those in there because I started out using Dynamic[list] and Dynamic[s] and kept getting errors.  For instance, StringReplace[Dynamic[list].....] gives and error.  I'll clean the code.  But the question remains, how can I make it dynamic?

Comment: @YequalsX `Dynamic` is a wrapper that the front end handles, so you can't just act like it's the same as the variable. Doing anything like `Dynamic[{1,2,3}][[1]]` or `Sin[Dynamic[x]]` will not work. What you should do is to keep the wrapper on the outer level, and put your operations inside, e.g: `Dynamic[{1,2,3}[[1]]]` and `Dynamic[Sin[x]]`.

Comment: I've put the Dynamic in every conceivable location and it won't work.  I'm getting an error in the ListPlot.  It says that s is not a list whenever I have Dynamic.  No matter what level I put Dynamic at.

Comment: @YequalsX see my answer, you need the dynamics to wrap the expressions that you want to be dynamicly updated.

Comment: Would you consider using `Manipulate` like in `Manipulate[
 s = ToExpression[StringReplace[list, {"(" -> "{", ")" -> "}"}]]; 
 ListPlot[s, PlotStyle -> PointSize[0.05], 
  PlotRange -> All], {{list, "((5, 6), (9, 0))", "Data points"}, 
  "((5, 6), (9, 0))"}]` ?

Comment: @b.gatessucks I'll try that.  I had not considered using Manipulate.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a simple fix for your problem.

```
 DynamicModule[{list = "((5, 6), (9, 0))", s}, Panel[Column[{

  InputField[Dynamic[list], String, FieldSize -> {50, 5}], 
  Dynamic[s = ToExpression[StringReplace[list, {"(" -> "{", ")" -> "}"}]]], 
  Dynamic[ListPlot[s, PlotStyle -> PointSize[0.05]]]

  }]]]
```

When using `Dynamic[expression]` I would suggest thinking of it as a message to the front-end saying: "Hey, rather then just showing `expression`, could you keep it updated if something changes?".
You can't just wrap Dynamic around every variable and expect expressions down the line to also be Dynamic. And as I stated in a comment, using operations on a `Dynamic` wrapped object won't give you the dynamic result of that operation on the variable.

This of course seems to clash with every built-in function that accepts dynamic arguments, for instance `Slider[Dynamic[a]]`. Since that returns a dynamic slider, you wold think that your function `f[a_,b_]:=a+b` would return a dynamicly updated value if you just ran: `f[Dynamic[v1], Dynamic[v2]]`. What instead happens is that the dynamic wrappers prevent evaluation of the sum. The imporant point to remember here is that functions like `Slider` work because they expect a dynamic input, and can rewrap the dynamic around their controlls so it still ends up in the right place. For this example, you would have needed to express how `f` should handle a dynamic,  and could have used: `f[Dynamic[a_], Dynamic[b_]] := Dynamic[a + b]`, which would then work in the way expected above.

Comment: Thank you.  It works.  I did not try to put Dynamic around the s = ToExpression....  I was not aware that I could do that.  For some reason I had a mental block and thought that an assignment would mess up the Dynamic.  Thank you for your explanation and solution.

Comment: It gets even more dynamic if you add the otpion ContinuousAction -> True to InputField

Comment: @YequalsX Dynamic will only reevaluate if something that it depends on changes, so it's not the case that `Dynamic[s=a]` will run continually, it only runs if `a` changes. I expect this was the root of your caution.

Comment: @Rolf Thanks for letting me know this.  In my case this would be bad since it would mess up ListPlot while typing in a new point.  But I can see where this option would be useful in other cases.

Comment: @jVincent What you say makes sense.  My intuition said otherwise.  I'm not experienced enough in Mathematica to have good intuition though.